# How to add new CSS file to new PHP file

Tags: php, templates, css

I've made a new template file for Wordpress constructing the elements of the page via PHP and Wordpress recognizes the template as such.

Then I wanted to include a CSS file for said template (same folder) and went with the standard:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

but for some reason the PHP file does not load the linked CSS settings.
if I add

```
<? include('style.css') ?>
```

the content of it gets printed onto the page, meaning the php file can read it.
So why doesn't it load the CSS settings?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS links are relative to the current request URI, not your PHP file. Use an absolute path like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ) ?>/themesubfolder/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to your functions.php

```
    function add_script_and_style() {
      // for .css add 
       wp_enqueue_style('my-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/my_style.css');

       // for .js add
       wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/filename.js', false );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_script_and_style' );
```

Extra Info: Wordpress standard way to do

wp_enqueue_style  function for .css file

AND
wp_enqueue_scripts function for .js script file.

Thank you

Comment: Please add an explanation to why the OP should do that. And BTW, that line will not work as it is only part of a working code, and the correct file is `functions.php`

Comment: @Pieter Goosen yes functions.php typing mistake. And wp_enqueue_style is the standard way to add css style in a theme.

Comment: That line alone won't do it. Should be in a function hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts` :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Before downvote you should check the code i gave. And wp_enqueue_scripts is for add .js script AND wp_enqueue_style  for CSS . whatever please check my way. Thank you.

Comment: Please see [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanx for your ref. This is for add script and style throgh action_hook and also look this line i told, for simple way to do , you will also find this line wp_enqueue_style( 'core', 'style.css', false );  here.

Comment: @PieterGoosen For your better understand i edited my answer look for both Style and JS script. I hope this will help.